# What tag should we use for nodejs development in ethereum?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There's quite a few differences between nodejs and browser based development.

I'm currently using nodejs heavily for contract and back office application development and would be glad to find and answer questions on nodejs related issues with web3, automated testing, NPM packages, etc, but have no easy way to find them.

Can we get a nodejs tag?

Comment: I added the tag to http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/making-web3-js-work-from-node-server-code  Not sure which of your questions you wanted to add it to, but now you should be able to use it.  (I assume you weren't able to create the tag yet so I did after seeing 5chdn also agreed in answer below.)

Answer (score 1):

<s>I don't think we want a separate tag if people are using Python, Ruby, or other languages to build on Ethereum.</s>

Maybe [ethereumjs](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethereumjs) could be considered ?
See github.com/ethereumjs which sprouted from github.com/ethereum/ethereumjs-lib

They would probably like to add your code to github.com/ethereumjs...

EDIT: since Ethereum is a platform, adding [nodejs](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nodejs) also seems fine to me.  We already have [javascript](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

Comment: +1 for `nodejs`, ethereumjs is a different lib.